# Minimum Versions of Xcode and MacOS Needed to Submit Apps in November 2018

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have called apple developer support, been to the Genius bar, looked at the Apple Developer guide and searched online but am still having trouble getting a definitive answer to what are the minimum requirements for submitting an App to the App store in November 2018.

Apple wants you to use Mojave as the OS and Xcode 10. With a somewhat resource constrained computer from 2014, however, I'm reluctant to go all in.  My understanding is that you need at least 10.13.6 (High Sierra) to use Xcode 10.   I did upgrade to High Sierra at the genius bar but for some reason, they gave me 10.13.1 which I don't think works for XCode 10.

If I go with some flavor of 9, does anyone know what the minimum build of 9, ie 9.3 or 9.5 to upload is, and if so, the minimum, version of High Sierra that works with it.

Yet another wrinkle is there are issues with Xcode 9 and IOS 12.1 on the new iphone XS.  Even if you add the device files for IOS 12, XS uses an architecture called arm64E that is not included in older versions of Xcode including possibly 9. Xcode suggests there may be a way to change this in the build settings but I could not figure out how.

Comment: High Sierra and Xcode 10.1.

Comment: Ok.  I guess you mean 10.13.6  "Xcode 10 requires a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 or later."

Comment: Why would anyone use High Sierra and not keep it up to date? This is ridiculous.

Comment: Genius at Genius bar did yesterday.  Perhaps you missed from question? ' I did upgrade to High Sierra at the genius bar but for some reason, they gave me 10.13.1 which I don't think works for XCode 10.'

Comment: Yes but it will automatically want to update itself from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A higher level CSR at Apple pointed me to where this appears in Itunes Connect.  In November 2018, the minimum version for uploading to the App Store is Xcode 9 which works with High Sierra Sierra 10.12.4 and above.

Interestingly, you can upload to the App Store with XCode 6 but the project must have been built in XCode 9.   You can also use Application Loader 3 and above.